# D3.js Grouped bar chart with JSON data

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am new to `d3.js`. I want to map `JSON` data in grouped bar chart as shown in fig as example https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BLVz.png  .I know there is something wrong with my x scaling. According to my chart x should show the months and on y axis hours.It's giving me 6 bars but for some reason bars are getting overlapped on each other.Could anyone please help me out here.

JSON data coming from MariaDB as an object.

```
[
    {"name":"jhon","hours":"9","months":"August"},
    {"name":"jack","hours":"8","months":"August"},
    {"name":"jhon","hours":"7","months":"July"},
    {"name":"jack","hours":"6","months":"July"},
    {"name":"jhon","hours":"4","months":"June"},
    {"name":"jack","hours":"5","months":"June"}
]
```

Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    .bar {
      fill: steelblue;
      stroke:black
    }

    .bar:hover {
      fill: brown;
    }

    .axis--x path {
      display: none;
    }

</style>

<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);

    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    d3.json("http://localhost:8888/index.php?r=emp/gethours", function(d) {

    var ydomain=d3.extent(d,function(d){return d.hours;});

    x.domain(d.map(function(d,i) {return d.months}));

    y.domain(ydomain);

    g.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(d)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d,i) { return x(d.months) })
        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.hours); })
        .attr("width", 40)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.hours); })
    });

</script>
```

After suggestion my modify data and code is

Bar graph generate for this is  https://i.stack.imgur.com/VowEA.png

```
[{"name":"jhon","hours":"8","months":"June","emp_id":"1"},{"name":"jack","hours":"6","months":"June","emp_id":"2"},{"name":"jhon","hours":"6","months":"July","emp_id":"1"},{"name":"jack","hours":"7","months":"July","emp_id":"2"},{"name":"jhon","hours":"8","months":"August","emp_id":"1"},{"name":"jack","hours":"9","months":"August","emp_id":"2"}]

<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke:black
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
                    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);



    var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    d3.json("http://localhost:8888/index.php?r=emp/gethours", function(d) {


                        var ymaxdomain=d3.max(d,function(d){return parseInt(d.hours);});
                        var x1domain=d3.extent(d,function(d){return parseInt(d.emp_id);});


                        x.domain(d.map(function(d) {return d.months}));
                        y.domain([0,ymaxdomain]);

                        var x1=d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]);
                        x1.domain(x1domain);

                         g.selectAll(".bar")
                        .data(d)
                        .enter().append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) {console.log(d,i); return (x(d.months)+x1(parseInt(d.emp_id))); })

                        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.hours); })
                        .attr("width",x1.bandwidth())
                        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(parseInt(d.hours)); })
                        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return z(d.emp_id); });



                         g.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));


                             g.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(null, "s"))
                                .append("text")
                                .attr("x", 2)
                                .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
                                .attr("dy", "0.32em")
                                .attr("fill", "#000")
                                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                                .text("Hours");





});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json Data

```
[{"name":"jhon","hours":"8","months":"June","emp_id":"1"},
 {"name":"jack","hours":"6","months":"June","emp_id":"2"},
 {"name":"jim","hours":"7","months":"June","emp_id":"3"},
 {"name":"tim","hours":"4","months":"June","emp_id":"4"},
 {"name":"jhon","hours":"6","months":"July","emp_id":"1"},
 {"name":"jack","hours":"7","months":"July","emp_id":"2"},
 {"name":"jim","hours":"8","months":"July","emp_id":"3"},
 {"name":"tim","hours":"6","months":"July","emp_id":"4"},
 {"name":"jhon","hours":"8","months":"August","emp_id":"1"},
 {"name":"jack","hours":"9","months":"August","emp_id":"2"},
 {"name":"jim","hours":"7","months":"August","emp_id":"3"},
 {"name":"tim","hours":"8","months":"August","emp_id":"4"}]
```

And The Answer ---------------------------------------------------------

Grouped Bar Graph Image  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ud5S.png

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke:black
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: brown;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

</style>
<svg width="600" height="600"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;

                var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
                    y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);



    var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);

    d3.json("http://localhost:8888/index.php?r=emp/gethours", function(d) {


                    var ymaxdomain=d3.max(d,function(d){return d.hours;});
                        x.domain(d.map(function(d) {return d.months}));
                        y.domain([0,ymaxdomain]);

                    var x1=d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]);
                        x1.domain(d.map(function(d) {return d.emp_id;}));

                         g.selectAll(".bar")
                        .data(d)
                        .enter().append("rect")
                        .attr("x", function(d,i) {return (x(d.months)+x1(d.emp_id)); })

                        .attr("y", function(d) {return y(d.hours); })
                        .attr("width",x1.bandwidth())
                        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.hours); })
                        .attr("fill", function(d,i) { return z(d.emp_id); });

                            g.append("g")
                            .attr("class", "axis")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                            .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

                                g.append("g")
                                .attr("class", "axis")
                                .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
                                .append("text")
                                .attr("x", 2)
                                .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
                                .attr("dy", "0.32em")
                                .attr("fill", "#000")
                                .attr("font-weight", "bold")
                                .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                                .text("Hours");

});

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for help Lary Ciminera.

Answer (score 0):

like in https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 you need a second x axis to move your rect for each "group".
look at `var x1;`  its domain is `.rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);`.

in your code you can the do

```
   var  d = [
        {"name":"jhon","hours":"9","months":"August","group":0},
        {"name":"jack","hours":"8","months":"August","group":1},
        {"name":"jhon","hours":"7","months":"July","group":0},
        {"name":"jack","hours":"6","months":"July","group":1},
        {"name":"jhon","hours":"4","months":"June","group":0},
        {"name":"jack","hours":"5","months":"June","group":1}
    ]

x1.domain([0,1]) 
...
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.months)+x1(d.group) })
```

Comment: Thanks for solution Lary however i can't modify my JSON data as it is coming from database with join query.

Comment: you can always do a d.forEach in your js to "hydrate" your data, or make a function that define the group value depending on you data, you can achieve it without modifying your data, do you need an exemple?

Comment: Sure sir that would be really help full.Please do it according to my data so that i could grasp it easily..

Comment: on let me take a look

Answer (score 0):

oh i found your problem
change

```
var ydomain=d3.extent(d,function(d){return d.hours;});
```

to

```
var ymaxdomain=d3.max(d,function(d){return d.hours;});
    y.domain([0,ymaxdomain]);
```

your minimum value on the y axis was 4 instead of 0

Edit :
also you have to do move the definition of the range of x1 AFTER defining the x domain :

```
    x.domain(d.map(function(d,i) {return d.months}));
// this should go after
     var x1=d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]);
```

Comment: move 
    var x1=d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, x.bandwidth()]); after 
        x.domain(d.map(function(d,i) {return d.months}));

Comment: i edited my answer to fix your second axis problem, x1 depend on x bandwidth that depend on x domain so you have do it after. try it, it works for me

Comment: well i cant upload anymore images.Now they have gap between them which i don't want.i ll remove the second image please check the second link of image and one thing i want to mention you are are really helpful person.

Comment: Change rect width to x1.bandwidth

Comment: I did that and thanks to that it worked but for more date it does't work                              [{"hours":"5","months":"June","emp_id":"1"},{"hours":"4","months":"June","emp_id":"2"},{"hours":"6","months":"June","emp_id":"3"},{"hours":"6","months":"July","emp_id":"1"},{"hours":"7","months":"July","emp_id":"2"},{"hours":"8","months":"July","emp_id":"3"},{"hours":"8","months":"August","emp_id":"1"},{"hours":"9","months":"August","emp_id":"2"},{"hours":"5","months":"August","emp_id":"3"}]

Comment: d3.extent,d3.scaleLinear and d3.max  need numeracal value, you can either change your dataset so hours and emp_id are numerical or use parseInt(d.hours) in your javascript : https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#extent https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear  
   https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#max

Comment: Thanks Lary for your valuable time and suggestions .You really helped me a lot .I ll see what I can get from this .Thanks once again.